# Open-Source Temperature Logger (HELP)

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, usb, atmega32u4

I am almost finished with the development of an open-source temperature logger (USB + battery powered). I have built the PCB using ATMEL ATMEGA32u4 with feather 32u4 bootloader (3.3V 8MHz). Its an easyeda project. But I have a critical issue that i an requesting help to locate the failure point.

I have the +3.3V rail accessible for an external power supply (for ISP programming and testing). the 5V from USB and ~3.7-4.2V from battery successfully gets converted to 3.3V on the +3.3V rail. HOWEVER, the +3.3V does not allow the device to successfully power up. If I apply ~3.6V or greater to that rail (override the LDO output), the device powers successfully and i am able to communicate with it. I cannot find the issue with the design, the ATMEGA32u4 should be able to be powered with 3.3V.

The device bootloader was uploaded using ISP.
avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega32u4 -U lfuse:w:0xD7:m -U hfuse:w:0xD8:m -U efuse:w:0xC9:m -U flash:w:Caterina-Feather32u4.hex

With +3.3V_RAIL at +3.3V, shorting reset does not affect it, HWB# is not tied to anything.
Schematic PDF:
https://github.com/bin2ai/mobile-temperature-logger/blob/main/hw/mtl_schematic.pdf
Github project repo:
https://github.com/bin2ai/mobile-temperature-logger

Comment: I think your efuse setting has put the brown out detector voltage at 3.5V, but I’m not experienced with AVR - https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf#page53

Comment: @Chase - Is there a specific reason that you used a 100k pull-up on the Reset line?  Did you want a slower power-on Reset? Note that internally there is already an internal 30-60k pull-up resistor on that line (RRST, per datasheet table 29.1), so adding the 100k will actually speed up the power-on Reset timing.

Comment: @Bryan - Assuming the fuses are being set as intended, the Avrdude command line shows the Lfuse should have been set to 0xD7.  That value should disable the BOD (per datasheet table 8.1).  The command line is listed on the github firmware page: https://github.com/bin2ai/mobile-temperature-logger/tree/main/fw ).

Comment: @Nedd 100K is used to ensure a known state, slower rise/fall time is okay. higher resistance, lower current draw.

Comment: @Bryan you are correct.  The issue was setting the incorrect brown out voltage.

Comment: @Chase - As in the prior comment the Reset pin already has an internal resistor pull-up (30-60K), so adding an extra 100K just parallels that, which results in a faster reset timing.  A larger cap would be an alternate method to slow down the reset.